# How can I move data from multiple columns and multiple rows to 1 single row in excel

Tags: vba, excel

I want to move all data from multiple columns and rows into a single row in Excel. i.e. A1, A2, B1, B2 into A1,B1,C1,D1. The reason I need this is so I can copy and paste a single line of text.

Comment: Copy then paste special, select the option 'Transpose'

Comment: Hi Jerry, that doesn't really work as the cells contain formulas to get the Titles/descriptions/data.

Comment: Also select 'Values' when pasting special then.

Comment: Hi Jerry, but i want A4,B4,C4 to also be underneath so it is just one long list in column A?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

below code will transpose the data from sheet1 to sheet2 for 4 cols, let me know if this is what you needed.

```
    Sub trans()
Dim x, y As Integer


x = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("xfd3").End(xlToLeft).Column
y = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("a65536").End(xlUp).Row

For j = 1 To y
    For p = 1 To 4
    Z = Sheets("Sheet2").Range("A65536").End(xlUp).Row
       Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(j + 2, p).Copy
       Sheets("Sheet2").Range("A" & Z + 1).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
       :=False, Transpose:=False

        Next p
    Next j


End Sub
```

Comment: Using Rows.Count is better than hard coded 65536 like `y = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row`.
`

Comment: Hi Apurv, I have slightly adapted what you have written above. Do you know how to do a paste special with your copy to keep the values that are being copied rather than the formula?

Answer (score 2):

I think what you need is more complex than what your question suggests. I'd personally copy/paste the whole thing in a text editor (notepad++ for instance), then replace tab characters with newline characters, then copy/paste those back in excel.

If that's not an option, I would suggest using some math (the original data is on Sheet1):

```
=INDEX(Sheet1!$A$3:$C$4,INT((ROW()-1)/3)+1,MOD(ROW()-1,3)+1)
```

Change `Sheet1!$A$3:$C$4` appropriately. When you get #REF!, it means it's the end of the table.

[image]

Comment: Hi Jerry, the problem with that is that the paste does not maintain the text formatting which is applied in excel? Any ideas on how to keep that?

Comment: Strictly speaking, this requirement was not in the question, but you can "copy > paste special > transpose and formatting" from the original table to the first 3 cells of the list. The copy that and paste it on the remaining cells from the list, as formatting only.